# How do I turn this string into a list, and then make it have a max line length in python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

So I have a big script that I have defined as text. I'm attempting to turn them into a list, and then when the user inputs a number, that will be the maximum length of the line, putting all characters after that maximum length on the next line.

```
def main():
    lmax = input("What would you like the maximum line length to be?")
    text='''Mother: Hi, honey.
    Grandson: Hi, Mom.
    Mother: You feeling any better?
    Grandson: A little bit.
    Mother: Guess what?
    Grandson: What?
    Mother: Your Grandfather's here.
    Grandson: Mom, can't you tell him I'm sick?
    Mother: You're sick? That's why he's here.
    Grandson: He'll pinch my cheek. I hate that.
    Mother: Maybe he won't.
    Grandfather: Heyyyy!! How's the sickie? Heh?
    Mother: I think I'll leave you two pals alone.
    Grandfather: I brought you a special present.
    Grandson: What is it?
    Grandfather: Open it up.
    Grandson: A book?
    Grandfather: That's right. When I was your age, television was called books. And this is a special book. It was the book my father used to read to me when I was sick, and I used to read it to your father. And today I'm gonna read it to you.
    Grandson: Has it got any sports in it?
    Grandfather: Are you kidding? Fencing, fighting, torture, revenge, giants, monsters, chases, escapes, true love, miracles...
    Grandson: Doesn't sound too bad. I'll try to stay awake.
    Grandfather: Oh, well, thank you very much, very nice of you. Your vote of confidence is overwhelming. All right. The Princess Bride, by S. Morgenstern. Chapter One. Buttercup was raised on a small farm in the country of Florin.'''
    lines = text.split('\n')
    count = 0
    for line in lines:
        count += 1
        text = line.split()
        out = ' '.join(text)
        if str(len(out))>lmax:
            newout=line.split('\n')
            print(str(count).rjust(3)+'/'+newout+'/'+str(len(newout)))
            print(str(count).rjust(3)+'/'+newout+'/'+str(lmax - len(newout)))
        elif str(len(out))<lmax:
            print(str(count).rjust(3)+'/'+out+'/'+str(len(out)))
```

I believe I'm somewhat on the correct path, but I'm not 100% sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Part of standard library: [**`textwrap`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the following way

```
import textwrap
n = input("Max length: ")
# for line in text.split("\n"):
for line in text.splitlines():
    print(textwrap.fill(textwrap.dedent(line), n))
```

Comment: FYI, `text.splitlines()` is a little more direct here, and avoids creating a final empty `str` if `text` happens to end with a newline.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Roger sir. I am editing it as per your input.